# Changing thickness of outline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, outline

[image: This is the problem]

How to change the thickness of this outline in QGIS?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to display all symbology properties by scrolling down (or enlarge the properties window) and change the **Outline width** value.

[image]

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply for QGIS on OSX