# Slurred outline in QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, outline

[image: problem]

Why red outline is slurred ? I changed "outline widght" from 0,25 mm to 1,5 cm and problem is the same.
Black outline got same settings like red, only size is different.

Comment: It seemed that you have this issue also in previous question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223700/changing-thickness-of-outline-in-qgis), can you post your style settings? Not sure, but it looks like you have changed blending mode in *Layer rendering* section of symbol properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to your previous question ([Changing thickness of outline in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223700/changing-thickness-of-outline-in-qgis)), it looks like you have changed layer rendering blending mode.

Change **Layer blending mode** in *Layer rendering* section in symbol preperties to `Normal`

[image]